# Insert array of objects into MongoDB

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I wonder how I could insert array of objects to Mongo collection "root-level documents" with own pre-defined _id values.

I have tried `db.MyCollection.insert(array);` but it creates nested documents under one single generated _id in MongoDB.

```
var array = [

      { _id: 'rg8nsoqsxhpNYho2N',
        goals: 0,
        assists: 1,
        total: 1                  },


      { _id: 'yKMx6sHQboL5m8Lqx',
        goals: 0,
        assists: 1,
        total: 1                  }];
```

> **db.MyCollection.insert(array);**

[image]

> **What I want**

[image]

Comment: `db.MyCollection.insert(array)` should work. Are you getting any error message?

Comment: Insert process works and I am having the data in collection but I would like to have objects at "root-level" and now they are inserted under "0": {},  "1": {} and so on. I would like to insert all my objects as "root-level" document with my _id value

Comment: With the document you show us you can't get that result.

Comment: @sportsdiehard as user3100115  said db.collectionName.insert(array) will work for you, try using mongo shell for insert

Comment: I see you have edited your question after I posted my answer. Have you tried it? Further, you should not post using screenshots, please, remove them an paste in the question body.

Comment: have you tried the ```insertMany``` method?

Comment: As in 2019 this question is no more valid or need further clarifications. Since `MongoDB 2.6` `db.collection.insert` method accepts single document or an array of documents with having or not an `_id`.

Comment: @justdiehard , Have you  found a solution for this query ?

Answer (score 15):

[db.collection.insertMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/insert-documents/#db-collection-insertmany) is what you need (supported from 3.2):

```
db.users.insertMany(
   [
     { name: "bob", age: 42, status: "A", },
     { name: "ahn", age: 22, status: "A", },
     { name: "xi", age: 34, status: "D", }
   ]
)
```

output:

```
{
    "acknowledged" : true,
    "insertedIds" : [ 
        ObjectId("57d6c1d02e9af409e0553dff"), 
        ObjectId("57d6c1d02323d119e0b3c0e8"), 
        ObjectId("57d6c1d22323d119e0b3c16c")
    ]
}
```

Comment: is there a way to "upsert" many similar to this? i want to push an array everytime but mostly the items will exist

Answer (score 4):

Why not iterate over the array objects, and insert them one at a time?

```
array.forEach((item) => db.MyCollection.insert(item));
```

Comment: I have done this, but its not letting me to add "result/succesful" function into insert

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MongoDB Bulk](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/insert-documents/#insert-multiple-documents-with-bulk) to insert multiple document in one single call to the database.

First iterate over your array and call the `bulk` method for each item:

```
bulk.insert(item)
```

After the loop, call `execute`:

```
bulk.execute()
```

Take a look at the refereed documentation to learn more.