# How to insert Array of objects in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am very new to MONGO DB so please bear with me.I am having a problem my array of objects is not working properly .

Here is my schema

```
const playerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    stats :{
        wins:Number,
        losses:Number,
        xp:Number
    },
    achievement:[
        {
        name:String,  
        date: String
            
        } 
    ]        });
```

**Here is my document**

```
const fluffy = new playerModel({
    "name":"nic raboy",
    "stats":{
        "wins":5,
        "losses":10,
        "xp":300
    },
    "achievements":[
        {"name":"Massive XP","date" :"25-08-21"},
        {"name":"instant loss","date":"24-08-21"}       
    ]

});
```

however in mongodb atlas its only showing array...and i cant see the objects inside...
[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVIO1.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert array of objects into MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36887928/insert-array-of-objects-into-mongodb)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Make sure to search before posting. Chances are someone already ran into the same or a similar issue in the past :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema is correct, it seems your  input is wrong,

In schema definition you named it **achievement**, whereas in input document it is  **achievements**. Correct this everything will work as you expected.

### Explanation

The schema is expecting **achievement** and you inserted **achievements**, that is why it is shown as an empty array in the database. To avoids this kind of typos in the future, use the required flag.

```
const playerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    stats: {
        wins: Number,
        losses: Number,
        xp: Number
    },
    achievements: [
        {
            name: {
                type: String,
                required : true,
            },
            date: {
                type: String,
                required : true, // required informs for missing fields
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

Refer this [link](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) for more on validation

Answer (score 0):

You can use `insertMany` see the doc [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/).
Of course, a while loop should work find calling multiple times insertOne, though I advise you to use the `insertMany()` method.
If you're new to MongoDB, I strongly encourage you to have a look at MongoDB University's [MongoDB basics course](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M001/about) as well as the [MongoDB for JavaScript Developers](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M220JS/about) course.